# C++ map of objects erase when key not present

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have the following map in C++ (gcc):

```
map<int, EdgeExtended> myMap;
```

where the definition of EdgeExtended is:

```
struct EdgeExtended {
    int neighborNodeId;
    int weight;
    int arrayPointer;
    bool isCrossEdge;

    EdgeExtended(Edge _edge, int _arrayPointer) {
        neighborNodeId = _edge.neighborNodeId;
        weight = _edge.weight;
        arrayPointer = arrayPointer;
        isCrossEdge = _edge.isCrossEdge;
    }

    EdgeExtended(const EdgeExtended & _edge) {
        neighborNodeId = _edge.neighborNodeId;
        weight = _edge.weight;
        arrayPointer = _edge.arrayPointer;
        isCrossEdge = _edge.isCrossEdge;
    }

    EdgeExtended(int _neighborNodeId, int _weight, bool _isCrossEdge, int _arrayPointer) {
        neighborNodeId = _neighborNodeId;
        weight = _weight;
        arrayPointer = _arrayPointer;
        isCrossEdge = _isCrossEdge;
    }

    void setValues(int _neighborNodeId, int _weight, bool _isCrossEdge, int _arrayPointer) {
        neighborNodeId = _neighborNodeId;
        weight = _weight;
        arrayPointer = _arrayPointer;
        isCrossEdge = _isCrossEdge;
    }

    EdgeExtended() {
        neighborNodeId = -1;
        weight = -1;
        arrayPointer = -1;
        isCrossEdge = false;
    }
};
```

I want to do this (plain example):

```
EdgeMap edge;
int nodeId=18;

edge=map.erase(nodeId);
```

a) Is this code correct, does erase return the object that corresponds to the key? b) If yes, what does erase return when the key is not present? c) if this code is wrong, how can I check if a key is present, the object mapped to the key and then erase the pair from map. Keep in mind that performance is rather crucial, so I need the most efficient way.

Comment: "Keep in mind that... is crucial... so I need..." I am a little disappointed that for such a crucial application, you didn't even manage to google "map::erase". The first hit explains *all* of that.

Comment: @us2012. No it does not, because it does not say how to actually get the object that is erased. I am a Java guy and then a simple map.getKey(id) will do all that in a flash. I am converting a Java app to C++ you see. No need to be bitter anyway.

Comment: `EdgeExtended(const EdgeExtended&) = default;` is equivalent to the copy constructor you defined, and won't need fixing if you ever add members to `EdgeExtended`.

Comment: @AlexandrosE.: Here's a tip, when you tell the map to erase the object, it gets erased.  You can't get it because _it doesn't exist anymore_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) No, it is not correct. The [std::map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) method you call returns the number of erased elements.

What you can do is use [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to check if the an element with the given key is in the map. This returns an iterator to the element if it exists, to `end()` if it doesn't. You can pass this iterator to the relevant `std::map::erase` overload.

```
EdgeMap edge;
int nodeId=18;
ExtendedEdge removedEdge;
....
EdgeMap::iterator it = edge.find(nodeId);
if( it != edge.end() ) 
{
  // found element.
  removedEdge = it->second; // or removeEdge = std::move(it->second) in C++11
  edge.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: That answers how to check for existence of key and erase at the same time. So how do I get the object that is erased?

Comment: @AlexandrosE. the idea is that when you use `map::find()`, you have an iterator to the element, which you can use before erasing. It has to be a two step process.

Comment: Even better: `removedEdge = std::move(it->second);`, since `*it` is about to be destroyed anyway.

Comment: @aschepler very good point. I added it as a comment in the code example.

Answer (score 2):

> a) Is this code correct, does erase return the object that corresponds
>   to the key?

No, this returns the number of elements that were removed.

> b) If yes, what does erase return when the key is not present?

N/A. It simply returns `0`.

> c) if this code is wrong, how can I check if a key is present, the
>   object mapped to the key and then erase the pair from map. Keep in
>   mind that performance is rather crucial, so I need the most efficient
>   way.

```
auto it = yourMap.find(nodeId);
if (it != yourMap.end()) {
   EdgeExtended theObjectToRemove = *it;
   yourMap.erase(it);
}
```

The complexity of this is the same as for a plain `erase(nodeId);`, as `erase(it)` takes amortized constant time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with an iterator, like this:

```
typedef map<int, EdgeExtended> EdgeMap;

bool RemoveEdge( EdgeMap & myMap, int nodeId, EdgeExtended &edge )
{
    EdgeMap::iterator e = myMap.find(nodeId);
    if( e == myMap.end() ) return false;
    edge = e->second;
    myMap.erase(e);
    return true;
}
```